# Foundation 6 pagination, how to paginate a Table?

Tags: html, css, pagination, zurb-foundation

I'm new to foundation 6 but I need to paginate a foundation 6 table using pagination plug-in. How to paginate the table? How to connect table with the paginator?
here the regular code from http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/pagination.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns">
    <ul class="pagination" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
      <li class="disabled">Previous <span class="show-for-sr">page</span></li>
      <li class="current"><span class="show-for-sr">You're on page</span> 1</li>
      <li><a href="#0" aria-label="Page 2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0" aria-label="Page 3">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0" aria-label="Page 4">4</a></li>
      <li class="ellipsis" aria-hidden="true"></li>
      <li><a href="#0" aria-label="Page 12">12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0" aria-label="Page 13">13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0" aria-label="Next page">Next <span class="show-for-sr">page</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my table:

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

contents inside `<tbody></tbody>` are generated using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a Foundation mechanism to automatically paginate tables or pages.  You need to connect the pagination html to your data using javascript.

This is one way to do it: the javascript creates a separate `<table>` for each page.  It also adds a new `<li>` element to the pagination `<ul>` for each page.  Use javascript events to add `.show` or `.hide` class to the pages when the pagination elements are clicked.

This example is very contrived, but shows how you could implement this.  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/genestd/rz4k24hk/).  Note that the fiddle collapses the page numbers if it is displayed on mobile size

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!